# Angular7 production build css not loading sometimes

Tags: sass, angular7

We have a angular 7 production build generated by (ng build --prod) deployed in apache server, Sometimes the css not loading so the site design breaks. Please suggest how to fix this issue

app.component.html

```
<main class="main-container">
    <app-header></app-header>
    <ngx-spinner
        bdColor = "rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8)"
        size = "medium"
        color = "#047bf8"
        type = "ball-clip-rotate">
    </ngx-spinner>
    <section class="inner-container">
        <router-outlet  (activate)="onActivate($event)"></router-outlet>
    </section>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
</main>
```

angular.json asseys

```
"assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/robots.txt",
              "src/sitemap.xml",
              "src/google657942afe23b31db.html",
              "src/assets",
              "src/.htaccess"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss",
              "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid.scss",
              "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular.scss",
              "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands.scss",
              "node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/scss/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss",
              "node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/scss/mdb-free.scss",
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "src/assets/js/tawk.js",
              "src/assets/js/smart-look.js",
              "src/assets/js/ga.js",
              "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js",
              "node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js"
            ]
```

Comment: Try including some code which could elaborate your problem.

Comment: I have updated question with source code